# Why can't I query encrypted password by sha1 from Database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, sha1

I have a record in my SQL Sever database like:

```
Use_Name: admin1 
// see comment on answer below: this hash is wrong. 
Use_Password: 7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b
reverses -> 123456
```

My problem is: password after encrypted cannot be found by

```
var user = db.Users.Where(b => b.Use_Name == name)
                   .Where(b => b.Use_Password == passSHA1)
                   .ToList<User>();
```

in

```
public bool Login(string name, string password)
{
    try
    {
       string passSHA1;
       passSHA1 = ToSHA1(password);

       var user = db.Users.Where(b => b.Use_Name == name)
                          .Where(b => b.Use_Password == passSHA1)
                          .ToList<User>();

       if (user.Any())
       {
          return true;
       }
       else
       {
          return false;
       }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
        throw new Exception("UserBO.Login" + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here is my convert to SHA1 function:

```
private string ToSHA1 (string pass) {
    SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass);
    bs = sha1.ComputeHash(bs);
    System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    foreach (byte b in bs) {
         s.Append(b.ToString("x1").ToLower());
    }

    pass = s.ToString();
    return pass;
}
```

Not find any record. how can I fix this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: print `passSHA1` and check whether both are equal.

Comment: Your code is catching and ignoring all exceptions.  For all you know there could be an exception being thrown but the method interprets that as simply returning false.

Comment: yes i texted passSHA1 is equal to Use_Password, but the "var user" still NULL

Comment: Not sure if it matters but maybe use `&&` instead of the double `.Where()` ?

Comment: And: the Use_Name should be unique. You don't need the password in a Where clause, just verify after you have found the user.

Comment: Dear Henk, i can't use &&, it's syntax error.! just .Where().

Comment: `.Where(b => b.Use_Name == name && b.Use_Password == passSHA1)`

Comment: Verify database column type, because some implicit casting may not work both ways.

Comment: You should use a slow salted hash instead of SHA-1. See [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) for details. Once you introduce a salt, your approach won't work anymore. You should read the database entry for the given user and then verify the hash in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to check method that put records in your database, because `ToSHA1("123456") == "7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b"` is `false`.

Looks like some sort of copy paste issue because `ToSHA("123456")` is almost a half of your hash: `7c4a8d9ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b`